# Excell Marco Import/Clear

Tags: excel, vba

So on a project I'm working on I need a macro button to accomplish multiple things for example
I have 3 worksheets, Overview, Info, Import

On the import worksheet information is pasted in and I want to click a button to basically copy and paste values that It has read into set rows after the formula is calculated but taking into consideration of the date

So Example

I want it to read worksheet Info Cell R1 if Cell R1 Date Matches with worksheet Overview G4,I4,K4,M4,O4,Q4,S4 (each day of the week) it will copy the text in that row then paste as values then clear the worksheet import where the information was pulled from

The formula to calculate it is all done but getting the macro done to process it automatically is my weak point.